# jquery посчитать количество непустых ячеек в каждой колонке таблицы

Tags: html, jquery

```
     <table class="myTable">      
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
     </table>
```

Как посчитать количество непустых ячеек в каждой колонке таблицы с помощью Jquery и отобразить результаты в первой строке после заголовков если столбцов в таблице 60 штук и строк больше 500?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только не очень понял, куда именно надо вывести результаты, поэтому пока вывел их в консоль, но суть от этого не меняется:

```js
const cols = $('tr:first-child').find('td').length; //считаем количество колонок
for(let i = 1; i <= cols; i++) { //в цикле по колонкам
  let count = 0; //создаем счётчик
  $('td:nth-child('+i+')').each(function(){ //в цикле по ячейкам каждой колонки
    if($(this).text() != '') { //проверяем, не пустая ли она
      count++; //увеличиваем счётчик
    }
  });
  console.log(count); //выводим результат по каждой колонке
}
```

```css
.myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.myTable th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.myTable td {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">      
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>ыва</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>ddgh</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>sdf</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>456</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>789</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>012</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>hjk</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```